# How do I Spatially Partition a whole lot of points?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, partition

I have location data of customers, with over 130 million records, spread all across the country. This is a Spatial Table in PostGIS

I want to now partition the entire country into 'service areas', such that each service area has:

- Atleast 30 Customers
- Is at the most 1000 sq km.

I have researched ArcGIS's Aggregate tool, but it does not meet my criteria, since:

- It does not take minimum count into consideration
- I only have Qgis & Grass at my disposal.

What tool/process can I use to Achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I ran small experiment:

- generated 900 random points
- connected them using minimum spanning tree
- picked sink somewhere in the middle

[image]

- flipped the links to form directional graph, i.e. each node
  eventually discharge into same sink

[image]

- ran script that I am using for aggregating smaller catchment into
  bigger ones trying to get average "size" of 30.

RESULT:

[image]

Let me know if this is of interest, I can dig up the script (it's already published somewhere on this site) or explain the workflow in more details.
I used ArcGIS.

## -------------------------------------

**UPDATE  Sept 2017

It is very similar to above, but using raster approach, Distance and Hydrology tools from ArcGIS. Tricky part is creation of minimum spanning tree and finding 'catchments' outlets in raster format.

These are the steps I followed:

- Triangulate nodes (points to cluster), extract triangular network
  edges, convert nodes to **WEIGHT** raster:

[image]

- Compute field in edges table: I use (ShapeLength^3/1e6). Convert to
  raster, fill gaps with very high value to create **COST** raster.
  This encourages flow between points close to each other. It is hoped that flow paths will look similar to minimum spanning tree (MST) instead of being near straight lines heading towards sink.
- Pick any node (OUTLET/SINK) and create Cost Back Link raster, using COST
  surface and  SINK as source. Convert back link raster to decent
  Flow Direction raster using `Int(Power(2,"backlink"-1))`. Accumulate
  flow using flow direction and weight raster. As one can see the trick
  with cost assignment truly produces something similar to MST:

[image]

I decided to group points by 50. Keeping in mind fractal structure of network I set the limit slightly lower INLET points at the start of 'High Flow Streams', i.e. Con ("FlowAccum">45,1). Inlets defined as cells where

*High Flow exists & focal statistics = 2 & cell is not an SINK (no data value in Flow Direction)*:

[image]

Use inlets as pour points and flow direction to define catchments. Picture shows 115 catchments derived:

[image]

Their statistics: mean = 50.33, min = 46 and max = 74.

To obtain second set of catchments it si enough to erase WEIGHT raster under already defined catchments, calculate Flow Acuumulation etc.

Method will work for millions of points because it is raster based, triangulation of that number of points is not going to be an issue either.

Comment: I don't know whether this will be usable for me, but it looks interesting as hell..Please post the script if you can.

Comment: I'll post script later today or Monday, took a day off work. In a meantime have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179559/how-to-group-10k-points-into-closest-pairs/179681#179681 where I described the idea behind it

Comment: I tested it on 100,000 points overnight. Last step took close to 6 hours and it makes it **no go** approach, not in ArcGIS at least. Not to mention that I had to code MST myself, because tool I by Patterson stuck.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? It seems I did using raster approach, can post workflow if this is of interest/

Comment: Please do. I solved it with a Bruteforce method, which was ok enough for my purpose; But I'm sure that others could benefit from your new aproach.